# How to route between two interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking, interface

I use a [`wireguard`](https://www.wireguard.com/) (a VPN) to connect to a server. This server has two interfaces (of interest for my problem - all the others are virtual ethernet links to connect to containers, no problem with these):

```
root@srv ~# ip a
(...)
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:5b:d3:1d:51:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.2/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 60366sec preferred_lft 60366sec
(...)
25: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 192.168.20.1/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The routing is

```
root@srv ~# ip r
default via 192.168.10.1 dev br0 proto dhcp metric 1024
192.168.10.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.20.1 dev wg0 proto static
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.10.2 dev br0 proto dhcp metric 1024
```

When connecting via the VPN, the following scenarios are **OK**:

- `ssh` to the wireguard IP `192.168.20.1`
- `ssh` to any other wireguard network devices on `192.168.20.0/24`
- `ssh` to any other device on `192.168.10.0/24` (except for the server itself, see below)

The one which is **KO** is

- `ssh` to `192.168.10.2` - the `br0` interface on the server where wireguard is installed

`sshd` is listening on `*.22` and I can `ssh 192.168.10.2` (to the IP on the bridge) from elsewhere (so `sshd` is functional).

This leaves me, I believe, with the routing between the interfaces. When a packets sent to `192.168.10.2` (bridge interface) comes through wireguard, its next hop is looked up in the routing table and it matches the line

```
192.168.10.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2
```

This is probably not good.

On the other hand, I would have expected the kernel to deal with this packet, understanding that it is intended for a local interface. Or maybe I am wrong here.

**My question: what should be the network setup so that a packets which comes through the wireguard interface can reach the local bridge?**

Comment: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` ?

Comment: @drookie  IP forwarding is in place (the packets to the other devices would not have reached them otherwise as they need to go though `br0`)